# What's an effective indexing strategy for a query with OR in it?

Tags: mysql

Below are the example query,How to add index with or  clause ?

```
select fild1,fld2
  from tablename 
 where (field3='XXXX' or field4='YYYY') and field6='xdffgfd';
```

Will the below index work ?

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX ind_name(field3,field4,field6);
```

Comment: Add the index and use `EXPLAIN` to see if it works.

Comment: What njk said, but you might need two separate indexes of (field3,field6) and (field4,field6).  I don't know off the top of my head how MySQL would handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not a good indexing strategy. The compound index you suggest will work for the `field3` lookup, but it cannot work for the `field4` lookup.

You will need a separate index on `field4` for that.  If you provide a compound `(field4, field6)` index in addition to a `(field3,field6)` index you'll optimize both parts of your `OR` clause for lookup, but you'll incur an overhead on insertions and updates.

Comment: I confused myself I agree with Ollie

Comment: Depending on the cardinality of the various fields, it is likely to be a better idea to index on `(field6, ...)`.

Comment: Yes ... Thank you.. 
Rewrite the query with UNION also works better:

SELECT fld FROM tablename WHERE field3='XXXX'  AND field6='xdffgfd'
UNION
SELECT Email,MatriId FROM tablename WHERE field4='YYYY' AND field6='xdffgfd'